# Write to CSV file in chunks at a time

Tags: magento-1.9, api, csv, importexport, stores

I am trying to write product data to a CSV file in order to export to a third party.

I need to break the operation down into chunks in order to prevent timeouts when writing large amounts of data.

The below code works but only writes the first 200 lines even though I have nearly 500 lines of products across three pages.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
public function uploadToApi()
{
    //Get the productIds
    $productIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', 1)->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));

    if ($productIds > 0) {

        //Create the product.csv file
        $csvFilename = 'product.csv';
        $exportDir = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/var/modulefolder/' . $csvFilename;

        $offerPrice = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('module/upload_settings/upload_to_api');

        //Need to get the stores
        $stores = Mage::app()->getStores();
        foreach ($stores as $key => $store) {

            $productIds->setPageSize(200);
            $pages = $productIds->getLastPageNumber();
            $currentPage = 1;

            //Unregister previously set shop_id
            Mage::unregister('shop_id');
            $storeId = $store->getId();

            //Create the array
            $products_row = array();
            $header = array('sku', 'product-id', 'product-id-type', 'price', 'discount-price', 'discount-from-date', 'discount-to-date', 'quantity', 'state');

            $products_row[] = $header; // CSV header

            $csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
            do {
                $productIds->setCurPage($currentPage);
                foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
                    $prod = $productId->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId->getId());
                    $data['sku'] = $prod->getSku();
                    $data['product-id'] = $prod->getSku();
                    $data['product-id-type'] = 'SHOP_SKU';
                    $data['price'] = $oPrice ? $prod->getPrice() : null;
                    $data['discount-price'] = $prod->getAttributeText('special_sale_price') ? $prod->getSpecialPrice() : null;
                    $data['discount-from-date'] = $prod->getSpecialFromDate();
                    $data['discount-to-date'] = $prod->getSpecialToDate();
                    $data['quantity'] = round($prod->getStockItem()->getQty());
                    $data['state'] = '11';

                    $products_row[] = $data;

                }
                //Now set the shop_id to make the API call
                Mage::register('shop_id', $storeId);

                //write to csv file
                $csv->saveData($exportDir, $products_row);

                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
                $callApi = Mage::helper('marketplace/callapi');

                $currentPage++;

                $callApi->uploadOfferData();

                //Unset the array() after first loop
                unset($products_row);

                //clear collection and free memory
                $productIds->clear();
            } while ($currentPage <= $pages);
        }
    } else {
        Mage::log('Products : no product selection specified', null, '_errors.log', true);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to create the CSV for each store as the merchant has multi-website setup.

I'm trying to write 200 lines at a time to prevent a timeout issue if there are very large product collections but so far I only get 200 lines when I should get 500.

Comment: How many total products? Can you increase your timeout on the server?

Comment: @brentwpeterson I can't do that